# Change Photoshop (CS5)'s 'Image Size' menu defaults

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Please tell me if this is the wrong stackexchange site for this and if so which one I should post it to.  And I apologize if it's the wrong one.

I take photographs.  I've taken a lot recently due to the Isle of Man TT (Tourist Trophy) racing festival.    Because the images are 21 megapixel I reduce the size in processing afterwards (also other processing as I shoot in raw).   I find that in the 'Image Size' menu I have to change the resampling type from 'Best for Smooth Gradients' to 'Best for Reduction' for every single image.  It's a small change, but it gets bloody tedious when you've got hundreds of images to work through.  Is there a way to have it default to best for reduction (bi-cubic sharper)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the preferences....

Preferences > General > Image Interpolation

Whatever you set the above to will be the default.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that option before,  but thought it was a general global thing, and affected how photoshop interpolates images while you're working on them.  Even if that's true I'll change it to save myself the tedium of having to change it manually for every image.

Comment: It is a global preference and Photoshop will use whatever method you set when doing things like Free Transform or Cropping. But that is also what is defaulted to in the Image Size dialog. There's no way to split the two that I'm aware of. Preferences are recordable in an action though. So you could record the pref change as an action and assign and F-key to the action. Then it would be a simple matter to hit and F-Key, then choose Image size.

Comment: New in CS6 is an "Automatic" setting, which will apply the applicable algorithm depending on what you're doing. (I don't necessarily recommend this as a best practice. But the setting is there.)